# "sync" vs."synchronization" tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [sync](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sync) and [synchronization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) tags don't seem to be differentiated in any way.

Should they be merged?

Comment: [tag:sync] is shorter to type and avoids those nasty s/z problems on different sides of the Atlantic/Pacific.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly.  There's only one counterexample I can think of ([Is execution of sync(8) still required before shutting down linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/115069/is-execution-of-sync8-still-required-before-shutting-down-linux) -- and it's lousy counterexample)

If no other counter-examples come up we can untag that one and make with the merging. (synchronization <- sync)

Comment: `sync` is a system call / command, so I suppose a *very* slim case exists for keeping the tag for that command and untagging/retagging the rest.

Comment: @Andrew I agree, but I only found the one counter-example I noted above in all of recorded history.  There are probably good arguments to be made for saving sync as in `sync()` though when talking about performance optimization and *avoiding* said syscall...

Answer (score 2):

I think they should be synonymized.

[synchronization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) -> [sync](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sync)

Answer (score 0):

Do either of them need to exist?  If it were the only tag on a question, it wouldn't do much to categorize it.

Comment: True, but the same argument can be made for "replication", but I feel that's a valuable semi-meta tag...

Comment: Throw 'em all into the void. If your question is about a certain replication or sync technology, tag it with that. If it's a general question about how to sync files on a certain platform, tag it with that.